# Why is implicit resolution failing?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, higher-kinded-types

I am having some difficulty understanding why implicit resolution is not working in the case below. Hopefully you will have some insights on the problem.

```scala
trait Jumper[F[_]] {
  def jump[A](a: F[A]): A
}
```

```scala
implicit def conversion[F[_]: Jumper, A](a: F[A]): A = implicitly[Jumper[F]].jump(a)
```

```scala
implicit val optionJumps: Jumper[Option] = new Jumper[Option] {
  override def jump[A](a: Option[A]): A = a.get
}

implicit val sequenceJumps: Jumper[Seq] = new Jumper[Seq] {
  override def jump[A](a: Seq[A]): A = a.head
}

// What I would hope would enable chaining effects (i.e. composing Jumpers)
implicit def composed[F[_]: Jumper, G[_]: Jumper]: Jumper[({ type f[x] = F[G[x]] })#f] =
  new Jumper[({ type f[x] = F[G[x]] })#f] {
    override def jump[A](a: F[G[A]]): A = implicitly[Jumper[G]].jump(implicitly[Jumper[F]].jump(a))
  }
```

```scala
case class AddressPerson(city: String, road: String, number: Int, country: String)

val addressPerson: AddressPerson = ???
addressPerson.city  // obviously works, no implicit conversion occurs

val addressPersonOpt: Option[AddressPerson] = ???
addressPersonOpt.city  // works thanks to the implicit conversion and optionJumps

val addressPersonSeq: Seq[AddressPerson] = ???
addressPersonSeq.city  // works thanks to the implicit conversion and sequenceJumps


val addressPersonSeqOpt: Option[Seq[AddressPerson]] = ???
addressPersonSeqOpt.city  // does not work! I wanted this to work out of the box via `composed`
// error is: value city is not a member of Option[Seq[AddressPerson]]
//    addressPersonSeqOpt.city
//                        ^ 


// however, if I define type alias
type Alias[Y] = Option[Seq[Y]]
val addressPersonSeqOpt: Alias[AddressPerson] = ???
addressPersonSeqOpt.city  // works
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? Why is implicit resolution not being able to understand that we can convert `Option[Seq[Y]]` to `Y` ?

#########

Maybe it is relevant to say that I can overcome the difficulty above with the **different** code below, but I still want to know why the composition does not work.

So, alternatively, we can delete 'composed' and instead declare a new implicit conversion explicitly like so:

```scala
implicit def composedImplicitConversion[F[_]: Jumper, G[_]: Jumper, A](value: F[G[A]]): A =
  implicitly[Jumper[G]].jump(implicitly[Jumper[F]].jump(value))
```

And now it works:

```scala
val addressPersonSeqOpt: Option[Seq[AddressPerson]] = ???
addressPersonSeqOpt.city  // it works!
```

Lastly, before I get hate for using implicit conversions like this, consider this an hypothetical question of sorts.
I do not intent to be able to ever call `addressPersonOpt.city` at run-time!
If you must know, this it to be used in tandem with a macro.
I just need this implicit conversions to work, so that I can pass an adequate function signature and analyse it (the Tree corresponding to the function) with the macro only..

Comment: Please, don't do this. You are only making the code harder to understand, harder to debug, harder to change and harder to compile. You are also hiding unsafe operations that can crash your code.

Comment: This is the only way to achieve what I want. 
But worry not, obviously the intent is not to be able to call `addressPersonSeq.city` at run-time. This implicit resolutions will actually never run! This sits behind a macro, to which I need to provide functions like `(f: Option[AddressPerson]) => K`. But these functions will never be called. The macro just analyses the function tree.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but having to write some code using some implicit conversions that then are actually rewritten by a macro only makes all the _"harder"_ in my previous comment into _"impossible"_.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar to Chimney's dsl. 
The implicit conversions are never re-written. They are never used, they are never called. Imagine this. `def foo(f: K => V) = macro MacroImpl` where `K` could be `Option[Seq[AddressPerson]]`. The client of my library calls `foo` and it must provide `f`. But the `f` is never called. And this implicit conversions are hidden. Can only be imported explicitly. Then the syntax Tree corresponding to `f` is analysed in a way which does not concern conversions or implicits at all. Would you still have objections to this?

Comment: This is basically so that the user of my library can do `foo(_.city)`. Or alternatively `foo(optionSeqAddress => optionSeqAddress.city)`. This is very user-friendly. Again, the function the user provides will never be called. Some meta information will be extracted by the Macro only.

Comment: I repeat impossible to understand, I am not only calling code that is obfuscated by a bunch of implicit conversions. But actually, that code won't be called but rather a macro would do a bunch of stuff that is invisible to me and practically impossible to debug if i need to. - I mean, is just my opinion, I hate machinery, I hate code that is not clear, I hate things that work under my noose.

Comment: You can take a deep breath thankfully then. Try to relax. I am sure you will not be using this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the hint to the compiler to figure out what is `A` and what is `F`, if you don't create the type alias the compiler asumes `F` is `Option[_]` and A `Seq[AddressPerson]`, that's why the implicit conversion doesn't work, because the code doesn't compile after the conversion.

On the other hand, when you use the type alias it is clear to the compiler that `F` is `Option[Seq[_]]` and `A` is `AddressPerson`

Comment: Makes sense. That was my guess as well. Do you have any suggestion on how to go about this? Also, although it makes sense, shouldn't that mean the alternative I explain at the end (with the `implicit def composedImplicitConversion` ) should also have this problem, and therefore not compile?

Comment: type alias are relevant at compilation time, you are giving explicit type information to the compiler by using them. You are saying hey my F is Alias, so the compiler dont have to guess what is F.